# Adding, editing, deleting rows of the grid using Struts2 jQuery Grid plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery-grid

I'm trying CRUD operations using a Struts jQuery grid using the [struts2-jquery-grid-3.7.0](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-grid-plugin-3.7.0.jar&can=2&q=) plugin as demonstrated on the [showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action), Grid (Editable/Multiselect).

**This is the form:**

```xml
<s:form namespace="/admin_side" action="Test" validate="true" id="dataForm" name="dataForm">
    <s:url id="remoteurl" action="TestGrid" namespace="/admin_side"/>
    <s:url id="editurl" action="EditTest"/>
    <sjg:grid
        id="gridmultitable"
        caption="Example (Editable/Multiselect)"
        dataType="json"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorSearchOptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"
        navigatorEdit="true"
        navigatorView="true"
        navigatorAddOptions="{height:280, width:500, reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
        navigatorEditOptions="{height:280, width:500, reloadAfterSubmit:false}"                
        navigatorViewOptions="{height:280, width:500}"
        navigatorDelete="true"
        navigatorDeleteOptions="{height:280, width:500,reloadAfterSubmit:true}"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="5,10,15"
        rowNum="5"
        rownumbers="true"                
        editurl="%{editurl}"
        editinline="true"
        multiselect="true"
        onSelectRowTopics="rowselect">

        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryId" index="countryId" title="Id" formatter="integer" editable="false" dataType="Long" sortable="true" search="true" sorttype="integer" searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryName" index="countryName" title="Country Name" editable="true" sortable="true" search="true" sorttype="text"/>
        <sjg:gridColumn name="countryCode" index="countryCode" title="Country Code" sortable="true" search="true" editable="true" sorttype="text"/>

    </sjg:grid>
</s:form>
```

A method in the corresponding action class is mapped which is called, while performing operations like adding, deleting and editing of a row.

```java
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value = "json-package")
@InterceptorRefs(
    @InterceptorRef(value = "store", params = {"operationMode", "AUTOMATIC"}))
public final class TestAction extends ActionSupport implements Serializable, ModelDriven<Country>
{
    @Autowired
    private final transient CountryService countryService=null;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Country entity=new Country();
    private List<Country> gridModel=new ArrayList<Country>();

    private String oper; //Getter and setter.

    @Action(value = "EditTest",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String edit() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(entity.getCountryId()+" : "+entity.getCountryName()+" : "+entity.getCountryCode()+" : "+oper);

        if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
             //Adding a row.   
        }
        else if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")) {
             //Editing/updating a row. 
        }
        else if(oper.equalsIgnoreCase("del")) {
             //Deleting a row.
        }
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public Country getModel() {
        return entity;
    }

    @Action(value = "Test",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, location = "Test.jsp"),
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.INPUT, location = "Test.jsp")},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "defaultStack", params = {"validation.validateAnnotatedMethodOnly", "true", "validation.excludeMethods", "load"})})
    public String load() throws Exception {
        //This method is required to return an initial view on page load. Nothing to see here. Leave  it empty.
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

While deleting, the ID (in this case, `countryId`) is always `null`.

While editing, `countryId` is null because I set `editable="false"` to the corresponding column of the grid. When it is set to `true`, it is retrieved but since `countryId` is a primary key in the database, it should not be edited.

How to get this ID while deleting and editing (while editing, it should not be edited)?

<sub>This is not especially related to `ModelDriven` anymore.</sub>

---

**EDIT:**

While editing and deleting, `id` field of type String in an action class like,

```java
private String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

is initialized to row ID (of a selected row) of the grid in question.

While deleting of multiple rows, it is initialized to a comma separated string composed of selected IDs.

Performing operations based on row ID of the grid is unreliable. They should be done based on primary key values in the database. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grid by default uses `id` field  of the entity (if it has) as a unique key for the rows. But if your entity doesn't have such name you can use `key` attribute for the grid column tag to specify the column name as a key the value used to pass to the action when edit or delete operations are applied. For example

```xml
<sjg:gridColumn name="countryId"
                index="countryId"
                title="Id"
                formatter="integer"
                editable="false"
                dataType="Long"
                key="true"
                sortable="true"
                search="true"
                sorttype="integer"
                searchoptions="{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','gt']}"/>
```

The `countryId` will be used as a key value for the row in the table and this value will be populated during operations.

Comment: While this is entirely true, can't we have a `List<Long>` while deleting multiple rows? Instead, it initializes an id field in an action class to a comma separated string of ids while deleting multiple rows. For example, if I mark 3 rows for deletion whose ids are 1, 2, and 3, the `id` field of type String in the action class will be initialized to a string like `1,2,3`. If the type of the id field is `Long` or `List<Long>` then, it will take these ids as a whole number like `123`. If the type of id is `List<String>`, then again it will be initialized to a comma separated string like `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
loadonce="true"
```

and search operation work.